# grunt not ignoring files and not ordering the files as per the command

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

Grunt is not ignoring files besides it's not loading the files as per the priority given in gruntjs Please check the image

Comment: You should include your grunt config code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no image attached, but did you add the folder or file to the .gitignore file after they were already commited? In that case you might need to clear the git cache. See link below

[How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)